# Custom Navigation Drawer like Gmail and YouTube

Tags: android

I would like to create my own `Navigation Drawer`

using the **current Material Design** for the `Navigation Drawer.`

A **good example** of this implementation is the **YouTube app**. 
In the App the `Navigation Drawer` overlaps the **Action bar** and is not below the action bar like in previous implementations.

I've tried following some example from other people's tutorials but they fall short of what I want. I have included some of the implementations that I have tried. I do not want to use a Library,

I want to  implement it . Is there currently a tutorial that applies the Material Design Patterns properly.

[YouTube Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av47N.png)

http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: the support library has `NavigationView` that you use and you can see an example of it here https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: @tyczj 22 I am having some trouble trying to import the project in android studio. It does not have a gradle Home file

Comment: check this,it might help you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768647/android-studio-navigation-drawer-like-gmail-app/34768685](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768647/android-studio-navigation-drawer-like-gmail-app/34768685)

Answer (score 1):

I used https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare as a reference. However I came across this tutorial that provides a proper guide on how to create a material design navigation drawer whilist also handling the click events of menu items 
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer