# Android Studio navigation drawer like Gmail app

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, navigation-drawer

We're making an android app, and there is something we want to add.
Which is the effect the Gmail app has.

You can choose which account you want to view (and the rest of the app will behave accordingly).

[image: Example]

**EDIT:**

I now already have a (working) navigation bar, but the things I want are the round icons in the header. I want someone to be able to choose the user they are viewing.

Comment: Check the latest edit, and don't forget to mark it as accepted if it helped. ;)

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother, but how did you add the "1" at the right ?

Comment: @Omer It's a screenshot from the Gmail app.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The effect you want can be achieved by using [`NavigationView`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) from the `com.android.support:design` support lib.

You can find a full tutorial on that [here](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html). And you can download the full source code from that tutorial [here](https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView).

And [here's another nice tutorial](https://androidessence.com/creating-a-material-design-navigation-drawer) that you could follow.

But long story short, that view is split between two main parts, a header and a menu part, and each one of those you'll have to define on XML.

As from that tutorial:

> **Header View**
>
> This View is basically the top part of the navigation
> drawer, which holds the profile picture, name and email etc. You need
> to define this in a separate layout file we would look into that in
> just a moment.
>
> **Menu**
>
> This is the menu you want to show below your header, we define
> menu in a menus folder, just like you define menu for your overflow
> menu. So basically NavigationView is a container for the Header View
> and Menu which you are going to use in your sliding drawer. So now
> that you understand the NavigationView we can start building our
> Navigation Drawer.

With that in mind, build your header as you would do with any other layout. And the Menu is defined somewhat like the Toolbar/ActionBar menu. e.g.:

**navigation_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_home"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_home"
            android:title="@string/title_home"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_content"
            android:title="@string/title_content"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_about"
            android:title="@string/title_about"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_exit"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_exit"
            android:title="@string/title_exit"/>

        </group>
</menu>
```

Then, on your `Activity` you'll just have to make a layout like the one found in the tutorial, using the `DrawerLayout` along with `NavigationView`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
 
        </FrameLayout>
 
    </LinearLayout>
 
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You'll also have to create some `Fragments` for each screen you want to display with this `NavigationView`. After you've done that, on your `Activity` you can handle the selection events by implementing `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { 
    // Your Activity
        @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.drawer_home:
                fragment = new YourFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.drawer_content:
                fragment = new AnotherFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.drawer_about:
                fragment = new AboutFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.drawer_exit:
                // TODO - Prompt to exit.
                finish();
                break;
        }

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new YourFragment();
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

        return true;
    }
}
```

As for your edit, the icons could be represented by an [`ImageView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). And to navigate between multiple profiles, it depends on how you've implemented that logic on your app, but as a "generic" answer, you could switch those profiles using something like a [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html).

Those tutorials will help you through that step:

- [Android spinner (drop down list) example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)
- [Android - Spinner](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm)
- [Basic Spinner example (Stackoverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097784/basic-spinner-example)
- [Spinners (Android dev guide)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Once you've set that up on your **header**, handle the item selection and change the user profile accordingly. (This last part depends ENTIRELY on how you've implemented user profiles on your app). But just as a head start, you could check the [android training site](http://developer.android.com/training), more specifically, [this part](http://developer.android.com/training/building-userinfo.html).

Comment: More perfect answer  . Move ahead #Mauker

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya what? Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I saw a blog post once that dissected the NavigationView template from Android Studio 1.4: http://androidessence.com/creating-a-material-design-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's appriciated.

Comment: I can'r figure out how to swich between fragments. I've got the home page called `content_rooster.xml` and I want to show `fragment_instellingen.xml`. I have tried what you said in the last code section, but it isn't working.

Comment: @Tvde1 that is another question. Feel free to create a new one but it is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @Mauker How do i change the navigation drawer menu on dropdown click like in gmail???

Comment: You have to use `Spinner` on the Menu Header.

Answer (score 3):

You should use  **[NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html)**

> It provides the framework for easy to implement material navigation
>   drawer with the help of inflate navigation items through menu
>   resource. Befor Navigation View, we have hard way to make material
>   navigation drawer using listview or linearlayout with custom adapter,
>   but now we just need to add Navigation View in DrawerLayout,
>   everything else will be handled by Navigation View.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <!-- Your contents -->

     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/navigation"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For this requirement You can check sample

1. **[MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)**
2. **[How To Make Material Design Navigation Drawer](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html)**
3. **[Playing with NavigationView](http://www.technotalkative.com/part-4-playing-with-navigationview/)**

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 1):

I think this [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) is what you're looking for. This library has a lot of examples. You can either use this library directly or read the source code and implement your own drawer.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this Material Navigation drawer using MaterialNavigation library.
Article about implementation is [here](https://proandroiddev.com/making-google-apps-like-navigation-drawer-material-design-c8781d9ff8c8).

You will just have to import that library and you're done. See demo code on below site:.

https://github.com/PatilShreyas/MaterialNavigationView-Android